Jupyter Notebook & Lab won't startafter anaconda's successful installation
It is around one year that some of my students got issues with Anaconda Jupyter lab/notebook; they all got similar errors, as below:
[I 2024-11-22 06:01:59.231 ServerApp] Extension package aext_assistant took 0.3674s to import
[I 2024-11-22 06:01:59.263 ServerApp] **** ENVIRONMENT Environment.PRODUCTION ****
[I 2024-11-22 06:01:59.268 ServerApp] **** ENVIRONMENT Environment.PRODUCTION ****
[W 2024-11-22 06:01:59.322 ServerApp] A _jupyter_server_extension_points function was not found in jupyter_lsp. Instead, a _jupyter_server_extension_paths function was found and will be used for now. This function name will be deprecated in future releases of Jupyter Server.
[W 2024-11-22 06:01:59.429 ServerApp] A _jupyter_server_extension_points function was not found in notebook_shim. Instead, a _jupyter_server_extension_paths function was found and will be used for now. This function name will be deprecated in future releases of Jupyter Server.
[I 2024-11-22 06:02:00.930 ServerApp] Extension package panel.io.jupyter_server_extension took 1.5002s to import
[I 2024-11-22 06:02:00.931 ServerApp] aext_assistant | extension was successfully linked.
[I 2024-11-22 06:02:00.931 ServerApp] aext_core | extension was successfully linked.
[I 2024-11-22 06:02:00.931 ServerApp] aext_panels | extension was successfully linked.
[I 2024-11-22 06:02:00.931 ServerApp] aext_share_notebook | extension was successfully linked.
[I 2024-11-22 06:02:00.931 ServerApp] jupyter_lsp | extension was successfully linked.
[I 2024-11-22 06:02:00.935 ServerApp] jupyter_server_terminals | extension was successfully linked.
[I 2024-11-22 06:02:00.940 ServerApp] jupyterlab | extension was successfully linked.
[I 2024-11-22 06:02:00.946 ServerApp] notebook | extension was successfully linked.
[I 2024-11-22 06:02:01.702 ServerApp] notebook_shim | extension was successfully linked.
[I 2024-11-22 06:02:01.702 ServerApp] panel.io.jupyter_server_extension | extension was successfully linked.
[I 2024-11-22 06:02:01.749 ServerApp] notebook_shim | extension was successfully loaded.
[I 2024-11-22 06:02:01.749 ServerApp] Registered aext_assistant server extension
[I 2024-11-22 06:02:01.749 ServerApp] aext_assistant | extension was successfully loaded.
[I 2024-11-22 06:02:01.749 ServerApp] Registered aext_core server extension
[I 2024-11-22 06:02:01.749 ServerApp] aext_core | extension was successfully loaded.
[I 2024-11-22 06:02:01.749 ServerApp] Registered aext_panels server extension
[I 2024-11-22 06:02:01.749 ServerApp] aext_panels | extension was successfully loaded.
[I 2024-11-22 06:02:01.749 ServerApp] Registered aext_share_notebook_server server extension
[I 2024-11-22 06:02:01.749 ServerApp] aext_share_notebook | extension was successfully loaded.
[I 2024-11-22 06:02:01.749 ServerApp] jupyter_lsp | extension was successfully loaded.
[I 2024-11-22 06:02:01.749 ServerApp] jupyter_server_terminals | extension was successfully loaded.
[I 2024-11-22 06:02:01.749 LabApp] JupyterLab extension loaded from C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\jupyterlab
[I 2024-11-22 06:02:01.749 LabApp] JupyterLab application directory is C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\share\jupyter\lab
[I 2024-11-22 06:02:01.749 LabApp] Extension Manager is 'pypi'.
[I 2024-11-22 06:02:01.905 ServerApp] jupyterlab | extension was successfully loaded.
[I 2024-11-22 06:02:01.905 ServerApp] notebook | extension was successfully loaded.
[I 2024-11-22 06:02:01.905 ServerApp] panel.io.jupyter_server_extension | extension was successfully loaded.
[I 2024-11-22 06:02:01.905 ServerApp] Serving notebooks from local directory: C:\Users\RaSa
[I 2024-11-22 06:02:01.905 ServerApp] Jupyter Server 2.14.1 is running at:
[I 2024-11-22 06:02:01.905 ServerApp] http://localhost:8888/tree?token=aee506bb54b16beb90787b9f72d3154f449b2f2589f46435
[I 2024-11-22 06:02:01.905 ServerApp] http://127.0.0.1:8888/tree?token=aee506bb54b16beb90787b9f72d3154f449b2f2589f46435
[I 2024-11-22 06:02:01.905 ServerApp] Use Control-C to stop this server and shut down all kernels (twice to skip confirmation).
[E 2024-11-22 06:02:01.905 ServerApp] Failed to write server-info to C:\Users\RaSa\AppData\Roaming\jupyter\runtime\jpserver-17000.json: PermissionError(13, 'Permission denied')
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Scripts\jupyter-notebook-script.py", line 10, in
sys.exit(main())
^^^^^^
File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\jupyter_server\extension\application.py", line 623, in launch_instance
serverapp.start()
File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\jupyter_server\serverapp.py", line 3119, in start
self.start_app()
File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\jupyter_server\serverapp.py", line 3023, in start_app
self.write_browser_open_files()
File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\jupyter_server\serverapp.py", line 2890, in write_browser_open_files
self.write_browser_open_file()
File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\jupyter_server\serverapp.py", line 2913, in write_browser_open_file
with open(self.browser_open_file, "w", encoding="utf-8") as f:
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\Users\\RaSa\\AppData\\Roaming\\jupyter\\runtime\\jpserver-17000-open.html'


I couldn't recreate this error to solve it. since these students are new to programming, if it possible, I want an simple solution.
Best Regards

See here.

Set an ENV variable to override the runtime directory. See: https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/7421 and https://docs.jupyter.org/en/latest/use/jupyter-directories.html#envvar-JUPYTER_RUNTIME_DIR
